# Filter XML Data in Powershell and save to target folder in same XML format

Tags: powershell

I have an XML file which has data for different countries. I want to load the XML file using PowerShell, filter data to just show data for the UK and then save the result on to a new XML file. I am able to load the data, filter it but not save. After filtering the data, the top 2 nodes (dataset and data) are not visible in the target variable.

I tried loading the file using Get-Content, filtered the data using "$xml.dataset.data | Where {$_.country.startsWith("UK")}" and then used ".save" to save the result.

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset>
    <data>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Description>First test in the set</Description>
        <FilePath4>C:\Application\Apple.txt</FilePath4>
        <country>UK</country>
        <FilePath7>C:\Test\Orange.txt</FilePath7>
    </data>
    <data>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Description>Third test in the set</Description>
        <FilePath4>C:\Application\Apple.txt</FilePath4>
        <country>ROI</country>
        <FilePath7>C:\Test\Orange.txt</FilePath7>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

Data Load:
`$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content C:\Users\HybridPC-40\Desktop\Sample.xml)`

Data Filter:
`$xml1 = $xml.dataset.data | Where {$_.country.startsWith("UK")}`

Result:
`$xml1`
gives

```
Name        : Test1
Description : First test in the set
FilePath4   : C:\Application\Apple.txt
country     : UK
FilePath7   : C:\Test\Orange.txt
```

Save:
`$xml1.save("C:\Users\HybridPC-40\Desktop\Test.xml")`
gives below error

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'save'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $xml1.save("C:\Users\HybridPC-40\Desktop\Test.xml")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (save:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Expected result should be a new XML file with below data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset>
    <data>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Description>First test in the set</Description>
        <FilePath4>C:\Application\Apple.txt</FilePath4>
        <country>UK</country>
        <FilePath7>C:\Test\Orange.txt</FilePath7>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmlelement` as the error suggests dosent have the save method, its the `xmldocument` that contains it.

try this:

```
$xml1.ownerdocument.save("C:\Users\HybridPC-40\Desktop\Test.xml")
```

some tips:

## load xml

```
$xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.load("C:\Users\HybridPC-40\Desktop\Sample.xml")
```

using get-content to load xml can mess witht he formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
#creates a record of all or part of a PowerShell session to a text file. 
#The transcript includes all command that the user types and all output that appears on the console.
Start-Transcript -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Log\$($($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name).TrimEnd("ps1"))log"


$XmlPath = "$PSScriptRoot\Sample.xml"
# same too below ..
#$XmlPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "Sample.xml"

$SavedNewXml = "$PSScriptRoot\Test.xml"


$xml = [xml](Get-Content $XmlPath)
#$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $XmlPath)

$xml1 = $xml.dataset.data | Where {$_.country.startsWith("UK")}


$xml1 | ForEach-Object {
    Write-host "Writing to $SavedNewXml  ..."
    $_ | Out-File -FilePath $SavedNewXml
}

#stops a transcript that was started by the Start-Transcript cmdlet. 
#Alternatively, you can end a session to stop a transcript.
Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete data nodes other than the target node and save it.

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//data[not(./country/@value='UK')]") | foreach { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
$xml.Save("your xml path")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
[xml]$Country = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset>
    <data>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Description>First test in the set</Description>
        <FilePath4>C:\Application\Apple.txt</FilePath4>
        <country>UK</country>
        <FilePath7>C:\Test\Orange.txt</FilePath7>
    </data>
    <data>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Description>Third test in the set</Description>
        <FilePath4>C:\Application\Apple.txt</FilePath4>
        <country>ROI</country>
        <FilePath7>C:\Test\Orange.txt</FilePath7>
    </data>
</dataset>
"@

$Country.dataset.data 

# Results

Name        : Test1
Description : First test in the set
FilePath4   : C:\Application\Apple.txt
country     : UK
FilePath7   : C:\Test\Orange.txt

Name        : Test1
Description : Third test in the set
FilePath4   : C:\Application\Apple.txt
country     : ROI
FilePath7   : C:\Test\Orange.txt


($NonUK = $Country.dataset.data | Where-Object {$_.Country -ne 'UK'})

# Results

Name        : Test1
Description : Third test in the set
FilePath4   : C:\Application\Apple.txt
country     : ROI
FilePath7   : C:\Test\Orange.txt

$Country.dataset.RemoveChild($NonUK)

# Results

Name        : Test1
Description : Third test in the set
FilePath4   : C:\Application\Apple.txt
country     : ROI
FilePath7   : C:\Test\Orange.txt


# Results

$Country.Save('e:\temp\UK_Only.xml')

Get-Content -Path 'E:\temp\UK_Only.xml'

# Results

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset>
  <data>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Description>First test in the set</Description>
    <FilePath4>C:\Application\Apple.txt</FilePath4>
    <country>UK</country>
    <FilePath7>C:\Test\Orange.txt</FilePath7>
  </data>
</dataset>
```